# How to use foreach loop with ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I need to use ViewModel in my View but getting error Null reference exception (foreach (var item in Model)) (item = null). How can i overcome this?

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? page)
        {
            var pagesList = from m in _BSXCertAssignmentsItem.All select m;

            int pageSize = 20;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            var pagedPages = pagesList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize) as PagedList<BSXCertAssignmentsViewModel>;

            var idlist = _BSXCSRServiceItem.All.Where(x => x.SERVICE_ID != 0);

            return View(pagedPages);
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class BSXCertAssignmentsViewModel
    {
        public BSXCertAssignments certAssignments { get; set; }
        public BSXCSRService service { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model PagedList<BSXCertAssignmentsViewModel>
.
.
.
 @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="/BSXMCertAssignments/Edit/@item.certAssignments.CERT_ASSIGNMENT_ID">
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.certAssignments.CERT_ASSIGNMENT_ID)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.certAssignments.CERT_ASSIGNMENT_NAME)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.certAssignments.SERVICE_ID)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.certAssignments.REG_ID)
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:120px">
                                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.certAssignments.CERT_ASSIGNMENT_ID">
                                            <div class="bt_cl admin-bt-dl">
                                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o admin-icon pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.certAssignments.CERT_ASSIGNMENT_ID">
                                            <div class="bt_cl admin-bt-edit">
                                                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o admin-icon pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
```

I know that when i type "var item in Model" it should be null because ViewModel does not contain items itself, it just references some models, but this understanding does not help me to solve the problem.

Comment: How about adding a null check for the model?

Comment: Check your method `ToPagedList`. Problem is probably becuase that is not returning an object of type `PagedList<BSXCertAssignmentsViewModel>`.

Comment: Try this in your view `@model IEnumerable<BSXCertAssignmentsViewModel>`

Comment: replace 'var' with actual return type and try passing IENumerable. 
`PagedList<BSXCertAssignmentsViewModel> pageList = ....`